# Anaconda /Miniconda navigator not working I was trying to install but not able to do so, Script file is missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, miniconda

I was using anaconda navigator older version which was running python 3.6 it shows me upgrade to newer version but it failed for more than 1 time. So I decide to do it manually I go through anaconda website and install anaconda navigator's newer version. But from then problems started it was first time stopped opening from start menu. Then I started rectify issue with that. Then i uninstall both version's. Now i download again and then is searched in directory of newly downloaded anaconda which was in C:User\adwait\Anaconda3 but the script file was missing. So i again searched online and i found answer on github: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6258
So one of the comment was to use miniconda with older version. Miniconda3-4.6.14-Windows-x86_64.exe
While installing the file this error pops up.[Error while installing miniconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyoKR.png) Then this installation close with this message on screen.[Close installation message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZOPS.png)

With Anaconda Navigator or miniconda script file is missing after installation.

Please suggest some solution to this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Please do the follwing steps:-

1. Uninstall all Anaconda version
2. Reboot the system
3. got to https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/
4. Download the installer
5. Run the installer
6. Don't add it to the path
7. click finish when prompted

Comment: I tried same thing with even lower version it didn't worked.